# How to append <li> to a <ul> on button click

Tags: javascript, addeventlistener

How to append `<li>` to a `<ul>` on a button click.

I have tried below script, but want to have a number appended to the end of `<li>`. Like item 0, item 1, item 2, etc..

```js
var list = document.getElementById("list");
var add = document.getElementById('addElem');
add.addEventListener('click', function() {
  var itemsByTagName = document.getElementsByTagName("li");
  list.innerHTML += '<li>item</li>'
});
```

```html
<ul id="list">
  <li>item
  </li>
</ul>
<button id="addElem">Add</button>
```

Comment: Whats your real-time need ? Your JS is invalid

Comment: ok i improve code

Comment: Check the updated code and asnwer

Comment: I couldn't understand, can you elaborate or edit the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a example to get started.

**Note:** For production use you might need to handle the variable `i` through `server/session/local storage variable`.

```js
var i = 1;
var list = document.getElementById("list");
var add = document.getElementById('addElem');
add.addEventListener('click', function() {
  var itemsByTagName = document.getElementsByTagName("li");
  list.innerHTML += '<li>item ' + i++ + '</li>'
});
```

```html
<ul id="list">
  <li>item
  </li>
</ul>
<button id="addElem">Add</button>
```