# How to display entered text in an textbox?

Tags: javascript, html, css, textbox

I would like to enter a text in an input field and have it displayed in a text box.

I think it's easy. I need one Input for enter a text, a button and a textbox to show my text. But my code doesn't work.

This is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">

<script type="text/javascript">
function ausgabe(){
  var text=document.getElementById("text");
  var Wiedergabe=document.getElementById("Wiedergabe");
  var Text=text.value;
  Wiedergabe.value=Text
}

</script>
<div class="Webview">

  <div class="message_container" id="myForm" ></div>

  <form class="send_container">
    <input type="text">
    <button type="submit"
    value="Nachricht absenden"
    onclick="ausgabe">

  </form>



</div>


@charset "UTF-8";

.Webview{
  height: 400px;
  width: 300px;
}

.message_container{
  height: 80%;
  width: 100%;
  border:5px solid green;
}

.send_container{
  height: 20;
  width: 100%;
}

.send_container input{
  width: 70%;
  height:20%
  border:2px solid #1CE615;
}

.send_container button{
  width: 30%;
  height:20%;
}
```

Comment: Because you have only 1 input yout get the **first** input by using `var Text = document.querySelector(".send_container input").value;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you somehow did some misconceptions about id and naming, you are trying to access elements with wrong names - a solution can be the following:

```
  <input id="textField" type="text">
  <p>
     <input type="button" id="theButton" value="click me!" 
         onclick="document.getElementById('div').innerHTML = 
         document.getElementById('textField').value" />
  </p>
  <h3><div id="div"></div></h3>
```

Comment: Thank you. This one helps me! I try it and it works. But when i want to clear my input TextField and send an other message below the first message...  What can I do that the first message is not deleted and the second message remains underneath?

Comment: Something like that can be found here: 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43252275/how-to-append-li-to-a-ul-on-button-click

Answer (score 1):

I found few issues in your code, let me summarize that here:

1. For `input` element for user provided text you had the `<input type="text">` which should have an `id` attribute as well in order to catch by `getElementById`.
2. In order to find an aim element, you need to also provide a proper `id` or `class`. I guess with the `message_container` you can achieve that by using `document.getElementsByClassName('message_container')[0]`. Then you can set the value of that element with `innerHTML` property.

So based on my explanation I think this solution can work for you:

```js
const ausgabe = () => {
  const textInput = document.getElementById("text");
  const messageContainer = document.getElementsByClassName('message_container')[0];
  messageContainer.innerHTML = textInput.value;
}
```

```html
<div class="Webview">
  <div class="message_container" id="myForm"></div>
  <form class="send_container">
    <input id="text" type="text" />
    <button type="button" onclick="ausgabe()">Nachricht absenden</button>
  </form>
</div>
```

I hope this helps!